# The difference between griddb timeSeries container and collection container

Tags: database, griddb

- "GridDB has two container types: Collections which can have any type
  of row key, and TimeSeries which always have a timestamp as the row
  key"
- Reference: https://griddb.net/en/blog/data-modeling-with-griddb/
  rowKey for the collection container could also be set as timestamp so
  why have 2 types of container?

**What is the benefit of using TimeSeries container as opposed to using collection container with timestamp rowkey?**

Answer (score 1):

Time Series containers can use expiration, compression, and other functions that are not available to Collection containers.